# Intellij Angular autoimport from "$GLOBAL$"

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, import

I can't find any information about this, but I have to say that I don't really know what to google for.

My Angular project inside Intellij sometimes does these automatic imports from "$GLOBAL$"
[image]

As there is an error, naturally the program throws an error inside the browser.

*Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/app/application/application.component.ts 9:0-29
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '$GLOBAL$' in C:/pathToClass...*

Can theses automatic imports be disabled?

Comment: It is fixed in 2023.3 Beta: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62934. You can find it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/